# How to use environment variable in a string docker

Tags: dockerfile

I have the following dockerfile:

```
   FROM alpine:latest
   RUN apk add wget
   RUN wget --http-user=foo@gmail.com --http-password=asdfghjhgfdf https://my.datomic.com/repo/com/datomic/datomic-pro/$VERSION/da    tomic-pro-$VERSION.zip -O datomic-pro-$VERSION.zip
   CMD ["datomic-pro-$VERSION/bin/transactor" "config/samples/dev-transactor-templ    ate.properties
   "]
```

Andin the last line I want to run datomic-pro-$VERSION/bin/transactor but the $VERSION depends on the environment variable. How do I make the string take the correct environment variable? Currently it uses the literal $VERSION and not what's injected by the environment variable in the CMD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ARG` for passing build time parameters. And during docker build pass env variables as `--build-arg <key1>=<value1>` to `docker build` command

In this case

```
FROM alpine:latest
   RUN apk add wget
   RUN wget --http-user=foo@gmail.com --http-password=asdfghjhgfdf https://my.datomic.com/repo/com/datomic/datomic-pro/$VERSION/da    tomic-pro-$VERSION.zip -O datomic-pro-$VERSION.zip
   ARG VERSION
   CMD ["datomic-pro-$VERSION/bin/transactor" "config/samples/dev-transactor-template.properties
   "]
```

Then build your container as follows:

```
$ docker build --build-arg VERSION=122.345 Dockerfile
```

Here in docker build, now you can pass normal shell environment vars as well

```
$ docker build --build-arg VERSION=$VERSION Dockerfile
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have many environment variables and especially if they're meant to be secret, you can use an env-file:

```
$ docker run --env-file ./my_env_test ubuntu bash
```

second options
you can definer ENV in Dockerfile also .

```
ENV DATABASE_URL 127.0.0.1
```